# MySQL UPDATE multiple tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I've a million different answers to this question and they all seem different. There must be some way of explaining this in a simple manner?

If you have two tables like so:

```
Exhibition
ID *
DESC
CURATOR

Schedule
ID *
TITLE
STARTDATE
ENDDATE
```

Where each ID refers to the other, and each table is storing different things about the same object.

How could you go about updating every column with new information in one statement?

I've tried something like:

```
    UPDATE Schedule
    INNER JOIN Exhibition
    USING (ID)
    SET Schedule.Title =            :Title, 
        Exhibition.Desc =           :Desc,
        Schedule.StartDate =        :StartDate, 
        Schedule.EndDate =          :EndDate
    WHERE ID = :ID;
```

But to no avail. I feel this should be incredibly easy, but I'm just missing it.

Comment: extra comma on `:EndDate,`? what is the specific error? oh by the way, in this line `WHERE ID = :ID` specify the source table whether `Schedule.ID or Exhibition.ID` or else you get *"ambiguous column error..."*

Comment: @JW웃 I'm not getting any error, the columns just aren't being updated so I assumed I'd made a mistake in my query.

Comment: Does it work if you try it from the `mysql` command line or `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: `Desc` is a reserved word - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html Try escaping it? `Exhibition.\`Desc\``

Comment: @Sean it will work as long as it is associated with the table or an alias, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72e3c/1

Comment: Hmm. OK, maybe it's a false alarm. The query excutes correctly in the MySQL command line in PHPMyAdmin. It must be something else that's causing the problem. My bad.

Comment: It was possibly the ambiguous column that JW spotted. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Update it like this

```
UPDATE Schedule, Exhibition
    SET Schedule.Title =            :Title, 
        Exhibition.Desc =           :Desc,
        Schedule.StartDate =        :StartDate, 
        Schedule.EndDate =          :EndDate
    WHERE ID = :ID AND Schedule.refcol = Exhibition.refcol;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `WHERE ID = :ID` was too ambiguous. Changing it to `WHERE Schedule.ID = :ID` had the desired effect.

Thanks to [JW웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/jw)